# Interpretation of the first-order logic sentences

Tags: first-order-logic

I'm struggling to find an interpretation for the following sentences in which one of them is false while the other is true. Can someone give an interpretation? Or explain what the sentences actually mean?

1.$\exists x \forall y(Lya \iff y=x)$

2.$\exists x \forall y(Lya \implies y=x)$

Thanks!

Edit: $a$ is constant

Edit:

1. Everyone loves Anne iff John is everyone. (False)
2. If everyone loves Anne then everyone is Tom. (True)

Does this make sense?

Comment: 1. says that there is someone (x) such that (everyone (y) Loves Anne iff he (y) is equal to x). Thus, assume that the someone (x) is named John; we have that "everyone Loves Anne iff he is equal to John".

Comment: $a$ is a constant symbol?

Comment: For 2. assume that there are John and Tom that both love Anne.

Comment: Yes, a is a constant

Comment: The first sentence means that exactly one person loves Anne. The second means that at most one person loves Anne.